# JQuery LocalScroll/ScrollTo not working

Tags: jquery, scrollto, html5boilerplate, smooth-scrolling

I am quite new with jQuery and only have worked a tiny bit with it so this might be a trivial problem. I am also trying out to work with HTML Boilerplate for the first time.

I am trying to produce smooth scrollings in both axis with the help of ScrollTo/LocalScroll (http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html). The website will consist of boxes the size of the window with a fixed navigation on top. The browser window should then scroll smoothly to the location.

My programming so far can be found here
http://www.andylang.ch/2013/

Both scripts are loaded and I am trying to initialise them in the main.js file like this

```
//Smooth scrolling
jQuery(function( $ ){

// scroll both directions
$.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';

// Scroll initially if there's a hash (#something) in the url
$.localScroll.hash({
queue:false,
duration:1500
});

// Scroll settings
$.localScroll({
queue:false,
duration:1000,
hash:true
});
});
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to do it. Might be a workaround but it works. I put the whole page into a scrollable div that adjusts to the window size and set this div to be the target for localScroll.

Comment: I can only accept my answer tomorrow :), so if anyone knows any smoother solutions until then, I'm glad for suggestions.